# Adding a background color to an icon in a button

Tags: html, css, button, background

I just created [this code](http://cssdeck.com/labs/x5m2lttk).

As you can see, on the left side you have a red background color behind a grey icon, but the red background doesn't fill the whole left side of the button.

Is there any way I can fill the whole left side of the button with red background in the demo above?

Answer (score 3):

just add this to the .button's css

background-color:*the color*;

Answer (score 2):

Check this updated [cssdeck](http://cssdeck.com/labs/qclbtkyc). Added background-color to your button class (.button) and hover effect (on background-color).

Answer (score 1):

There are namely two CSS properties to do this:

---

#### background-color:

Use this attribute if you just want to fill the background with a single color. You can do this with the name of the color or with an HTML color code:

```
background-color: red;
background-color: #ff0000;
```

---

#### background:

Use this attribute to assign multiple effects at once, such as:

```
background: red url("some-image.png") no-repeat;
```

This will set your background to use the image "some-image.png" for it's entire size and then fill in the empty spaces the image does not reach with red.

`background` will also work in the same way as background-color:

```
background: red; /*<-----This is valid CSS*/
```

You also use `background` to implement gradients, which can be created easily at [Colorzilla](http://colorzilla.com).

Answer (score 0):

You can change the  `background: #f5f5f5;` to 
`background-color: red;`. See if it works. :)